# grid-template-rows = auto, forcing empty cell among auto fill

Tags: css, css-grid

using grid-template-rows: auto; to auto-fill my columns with elements works awesome. However, in a design pattern, I am working on, I want to be able to autofill across the row but occasionally I need to insert an empty spot. It is triggered by a media query... open to thoughts and ideas. HTML, CSS, SASS, JS is being used fyi.

Thanks in advance oh mighty StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

so I figured it out finally, with the use of grid-column-start and grid-column-end on top of some :nth-child statements.